# ListView animation resets on notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview, android-animation

I am trying to add an animation when new items are added to my ListView (It's a messaging application). Using the following code in the `getView()` method of my ArrayAdapter, this works perfectly fine:

```
    if (!entry.isAnimationDone() && SharedPrefs.accessSettings(getContext()).getBoolean("ani_message_send", true)) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_in_bottom);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                entry.animationFinished();
            }
        });
        convertView.startAnimation(animation);
    }
```

But my message app also implements message states (small icons that indicate whether the other person has downloaded or read my message). When this state changes `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called to make the UI represent this state.

The problem is, that if this happens while the animation is still going which occurs quite often, my animation will restart which results in a glitchy GUI.

I've been searching on the internet for a while now but I couldn't find a solution to my problem. Is there another way to implement adding animations, or is there a fix for this glitch?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Consider Not calling `notifyDataSetChanged` but instead getting access to the ViewItem (convertView) and change just this item instead of the whole list

Comment: But how can I get access to that View and change the image?

Comment: If you got a List Adapter you could easy save the View which you return in `getView` just keep in mind that theire reused on scrolling

Comment: But isn't there any better way to animate new List items?

Comment: you could try to animate them in `getView` of your adapter directly. I do not know a better way

Comment: Ok, that's what I'm currently doing and it's giving me these issues

Comment: shure, if you call `notifyDataSetChanged`ALL views get redrwand, which is causing you the trouble